# Using a macro which accesses a global variable within a plugin

Tags: c++, macros, shared-libraries, extern

I'm in the process of writing a set of libraries, where one acts as the **core component**, late binding others via a **plugin** API. Now the problem is as follows:

The core library contains a logging class along with a set of macros for lightweight logging.

```
/* File: Log.h */

namespace XYZ
{
    class XYZ_API Log
    {
        /* Logfile and console output management */
    };

    // Global log object
    extern XYZ_API Log logger;

    // Macros using aforementioned variable
    #ifndef XYZ_DISABLE_LOGGING
        #define LOG_DEBUG(msg) /* statements using logger object */
        #define LOG_INFO(msg) /* etc. */
    #else
        #define LOG_DEBUG(msg)
        #define LOG_INFO(msg)
    #endif
}
```

The definition of the logger variable is as simple as it gets:

```
/* File: Log.cpp */

namespace XYZ
{
    // Initialize the global log object
    Log logger;

    /* Log class implementation */
}
```

Now, when making use of these macros from within the core library itself or from a client application, everything works just fine. But once I try to use them in one of the plugins:

```
/* File: MyPlugin.cpp */

namespace XYZ
{
    MyPlugin::MyPlugin(/* ... */)
    {
        LOG_INFO("This won't link!");
        logger.
    }
}
```

The following linker error arises (using the MSVC toolchain v110):

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class XYZ::Log XYZ::logger" (?logger@XYZ@@3VLog@1@A)
```

That being said, this very symbol is definitely being exported from the plugin library (it is present in the .lib file). The plugin is also being linked against the core library. Other symbols (classes and their methods) work just fine.

I understand that for runtime loading, symbols from the loaded DLL must be queried with GetProcAddress/dlsym (or some equivalent). Furthermore, I have an interface in place which can, through a purely virtual class, make any object from the core library known to plugins.

Now for the **actual question**: Is there a way to make the above plan work or do I have to refrain from using the logging macros within plugin code?

**Edit:**

The compiler command line options (core library) are (lengthy path names stripped out):

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"[...]" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"[...]" /fp:precise /D "XYZ_EXPORT_SYMBOLS" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"[...]" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"[...]" /Fp"[...]"
```

And for the linker:

```
/OUT:"[...]" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"[...]" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"[...]" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"[...]" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"[...]" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Same thing for the plugin library; pretty much exactly the same line, save for path names:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"[...]" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"[...]" /fp:precise /D "XYZ_EXPORT_SYMBOLS" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"[...]" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"[...]" /Fp"[...]"
```

And plugin linking; Again, basically the same line except for the link to the core library:

```
/OUT:"[...]" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"[...]" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "[path to core lib]" /IMPLIB:"[...]" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"[...]" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"[...]" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a circular dependency problem.
I've tried replicating your problem, however I run in Linux, and it doesn't fail for me.

I assume you're writing for Windows, re: the LNK2001 error.  Searching for that error gives microsoft help pages.  They should probably help.

That said, what are you compilation flags set to (both compiler and linker)?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Well, I stumbled upon Microsoft's list regarding causes for LNK2001 earlier, but wasn't able to connect any of the issues listed there to my situation. Still, I added my command line options above, hope that helps!

Comment: I used to get these problems with incorrect library ordering, from memory. I can't see where you're going wrong.  Have you tried explicitly specifying `/EXPORT:logger` or `/EXPORT:XYZ::logger` in the core lib build, and also try `/FORCE` in the plugin lib to see if it helps getting past the linking error.

Comment: I'm so thick. I accidentally defined the same export macro in both library components. Because of this, `XYZ::logger` was declared `dllexport` for the plugin. No wonder that didn't work. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction ! :)